# How do you decrease navbar height in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make my navbar in BS3 to be of height 20px. How do I do this?

I've tried the following:

```
.tnav .navbar .container { height: 28px; }
```

Did nothing.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    height: 25px; /* Whatever you want. */
}
```

Appears to be able to increase the size of the bar, but cannot decrease.

What is a good way to do this while preserving the container's alignment, etc.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

bootstrap had 15px top padding and 15px bottom padding on `.navbar-nav > li > a` so you need to decrease it by overriding it in your css file and `.navbar` has `min-height:50px;` decrease it as much you want.

for example

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top:5px !important; padding-bottom:5px !important;}
.navbar {min-height:32px !important}
```

add these classes to your css and then check.

Comment: I was searching a lot on SO and Google, but this solution did it! Thank you!

Comment: With the standard 3.0 navbar, that simply does-not-work. At all.

Comment: When using `navbar-brand` inside the navbar, its padding also has to be adjusted same as `.navbar-nav > li > a`

Comment: This works, with a couple caveats. The navbar-brand needs to be reduced too. My working example is:   `.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {padding-top:5px !important; padding-bottom:0 !important;
 height: 30px;
}`
`.navbar {min-height:30px !important;}`

Comment: This only affects the links in the navbar, not the navbar itself.

Answer (score 55):

[Minder Saini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19576381/1204434)'s example above almost works, but the `.navbar-brand` needs to be reduced as well.

A working example (using it on my own site) with **Bootstrap 3.3.4**:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
    padding-top:5px !important; padding-bottom:0 !important;
    height: 30px;
}
.navbar {min-height:30px !important;}
```

**Edit for Mobile...**
To make this example work on mobile as well, you have to change the styling of the navbar toggle like so

```
.navbar-toggle {
     padding: 0 0;
     margin-top: 7px;
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This was going to be my next SO search. Thanks

Comment: i wish i could vote some more upvotes, people are just messing up with style on other similar questions but finally this one worked

Answer (score 25):

Instead of `<nav class="navbar ...` use `<nav class="navbar navbar-xs...`

and add these 3 line of css

```
.navbar-xs { min-height:28px; height: 28px; }
.navbar-xs .navbar-brand{ padding: 0px 12px;font-size: 16px;line-height: 28px; }
.navbar-xs .navbar-nav > li > a {  padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 28px; }
```

**Output** :

[image]

Comment: Its not responsive.

Answer (score 5):

**For Bootstrap 4**
Some of the previous answers are not working for Bootstrap 4. To reduce the size of the navigation bar in this version, I suggest eliminating the padding like this.

```
.navbar { padding-top: 0.25rem; padding-bottom: 0.25rem; }
```

You could try with other styles too.
The styles I found that define the total height of the navigation bar are:

- `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` are set to 0.5rem for `.navbar`.
- `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` are set to 0.5rem for `.navbar-text`.
- besides a `line-height` of 1.5rem inherited from the `body`.

Thus, in total the navigation bar is 3.5 times the root font size.

In my case, which I was using big font sizes; I redefined the ".navbar" class in my CSS  file like this:

```
.navbar {
  padding-top:    0.25rem; /* 0px does not look good on small screens */
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  font-size: smaller;      /* Just because I am using big size font */
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

Final comment, avoid using absolute values when playing with the previous styles. Use the units `rem` or `em` instead.

Comment: in my case just changing `min-height` in `.navbar` and `font` in `.nav-link`  fixed it in bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

The answer above worked fine (MVC5 + Bootstrap 3.0), but the height returned to the default once the navbar button showed up (very small screen). Had to add the below in my .css to fix that as well.

```
.navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one nav and you want to change it, you should change your variables.less: `@navbar-height` (somewhere near line 265, I can't recall how many lines I added to mine).

This is referenced by the mixin `.navbar-vertical-align`, which is used for example to position the "toggle" element, anything with `.navbar-form, .navbar-btn,` and `.navbar-text`.

If you have two navbars and want them to be different heights, [Minder Saini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19576381/315850) may work well enough, when qualified further by an , e.g., `#topnav.navbar` but should be tested across multiple device widths.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top:7px !important; padding-bottom:7px !important;}
.navbar {min-height:32px !important;} 
.navbar-brand{padding-top:7px !important; max-height: 24px;  }
.navbar .navbar-toggle {  margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 8px 9px; }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to the readers if you could add brief explanation of what these CSS styles do. :)

Answer (score 0):

**In Bootstrap 4**

In my case I have just changed the `.navbar` `min-height` and the links `font-size` and it decreased the navbar.

For example:

```
.navbar{
    min-height:12px;
}
.navbar  a {
    font-size: 11.2px;
}
```

And this also worked for increasing the navbar height.

This also helps to change the navbar size when scrolling down the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Simply change the default 50px navbar-height by including this to your variable overrides.

You can find this default navbar-height on line 365 and 360 on bootstrap's SASS and LESS variables files respectively.

File location, SASS:
bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss

File location, LESS:
bootstrap/less/variable.less

Comment: What exact files are you referring here to look for `navbar-height`?

Comment: If you're using LESS, the file is variable.less. It is located at Bootstrap's LESS folder.