# Increase bootstrap collapsed menu height ( when opened)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a basic site with bootstrap. I am using the bootstrap navbar, with the collapsed option for smaller devices.

I want to increased the height of the ".collapsed navbar-collapsed" so it takes more space in the page.

I would gladly show an image to illistrate my problem better but im not allowed to post images on here yet.

So pretty much when I view my navigation bar on a mobile device, everything looks great when the collapsed menu is closed. When I click on the 3 lined image to open up the menu, it only shows about 1 and a half navigation page buttons. Is there a way to increase this height so I can see all 5 pages that I have there, even if the opened menu goes over the jumbotron division below it?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="font-size:      30px;">Mark Wuerch</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="philo.html">Philosophy</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv.html">My CV</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">My Projects
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">School Project on Disabled Learners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Building a better school one book at a time</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Working with ESL Students</a></li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: See the aboutme / home part. How do I make that entire area larger so when I click on the expand button I can see all 5 pages I have.]

See the about me / home part. How do I make that entire area larger so when I click on the expand button I can see all 5 pages I have.

Comment: Please add code so we will be able to help.

Comment: edited to have code - sorry forgot

Comment: added photo to make it easierto understand.

Comment: You don't have to invite people to correct. On this site you will be corrected whether you ask for it or not. You can however always roll back using the [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30764867/revisions) link, and (hopefully more frequent) investigate **how** your post was improved (hint: maybe you can learn from that).

Answer (score 1):

the default bootstrap css `.navbar` has a height of 50px so you need to override that in order to increase your navbar

```
.navbar {min-height:80px !important}
```

to increase the inner elements as you said, you will have to use the media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        line-height: 90px;/*changing this particular line does a lot, this is where the increase and decrease are done */
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        height: auto !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
}
```

### [bootply Link](http://www.bootply.com/ns48Y4aIuT)

Since you need it for a specific screen-size, you can use this:

```
.navbar-xs { min-height:58px; height: 58px; }
```

You should take a look at this, just found it with much more answers: [Decrease the size of the navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576175/how-do-you-decrease-navbar-height-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Thanks alot of this has helped. However I still am having issues trying to make the the collapsed section height larger. Your solution has helped me make my navbar (when uncollapsed) in general larger.

Comment: iäve also added an image to make it alitle more better to understand ... finally have enough rep

Comment: Hi , Yes putting the info in the @media section does help. Though it still does not increase the height of the viewable box, only padding between the page linkes and the div where the menu page is.