# Navbar changes height size ... need it one size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make it so my navbar at [link](http://www.dinewine.com/startbootstrap-agency-1.0.6/index.html)

is not long in height. I have been searching for an answer to this without any real luck, although got close using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576175/how-do-you-decrease-navbar-height-in-bootstrap-3)

Instead of

and add these 3 line of css

```
.navbar-xs { min-height:28px; height: 28px; }
.navbar-xs .navbar-brand{ padding: 0px 12px;font-size: 16px;line-height: 28px; }
.navbar-xs .navbar-nav > li > a {  padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 28px; }..
```

but it stripped out all of my styles. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try to use custom class and use your style with !important but only for that custom class so it won't affect other css. if possible please post image or jsfiddle as site is ban at my end so can't check the site.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no need not use container inside bootstrap nav tag.
Getting rid of it has reduced the height of the navbar.

Comment: This should be comment rather then answer. Yes i understand you don't have privilege to that but you can't post such low answers too.

Comment: @Leothelion I have deleted it.

At bethabernathy:
You said "I am trying to make it so my navbar at: URL is not long in width"

DO you mean height ??

Can you also be more specific of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I removed the container and that worked perfectly. I also added the padding in and it is looking much better. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav > li > a {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```