# How do you decrease navbar height in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Below is my code for bootstrap 4

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-collapse navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded ">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link " >
            <span  class="icon icon18 icon-upload"></span>
            Input Data From Prior Month
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " >
            <span  class="icon icon18 icon-excel-file"></span>
            Export to Excel
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="navbar-text color-blue">
        *Data Automatically pulled from sources
      </span>
    </div>
   </nav>
```

there are various examples given for bootstrap 3 here
[How do you decrease navbar height in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576175/how-do-you-decrease-navbar-height-in-bootstrap-3)
but none of them seem to work for bootstrap 4, can anyone help with this one?

Comment: can u update your code to fiddle, so that it is easy to understand

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Decreasing the Navbar height is easier in Bootstrap 4 using the [spacing utils](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/#notation). The height of the navbar comes from padding in the Navbar contents.

Just use `py-0` in the `nav-link` and `navbar-text`..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-collapse navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded ">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link py-0">
                    <span class="icon icon18 icon-upload"></span> Input Data From Prior Month
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link py-0">
                    <span class="icon icon18 icon-excel-file"></span> Export to Excel
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="navbar-text py-0 color-blue">
        *Data Automatically pulled from sources
      </span>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The `py-0` class sets `padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0` on the items.

[Bootstrap 4 Navbar Shrink Height](http://www.codeply.com/go/hek9Lon9Ej)

Comment: FYI using different themes can really screw Bootstrap utils.  So try using vanilla bootstrap if someone is having problems

Comment: Easier yet, add .py-0 to the <nav> so you only have to add it one place.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, sgg. It's significantly easier than going through each link and having to keep track of their individual heights.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone like changing CSS to get the same result, try this method. In my case I have just changed the `.navbar` `min-height` and the links `font-size` and it decreased the navbar.

For example:

```
.navbar{
    min-height:12px;
}
.navbar  a {
    font-size: 11.2px;
}
```

And this also worked for increasing the navbar height.

This also helps to change the navbar size when scrolling down the browser.