# Changing size of bootstraps navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using this navbar class : `navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom` Which I use to display a bar at the bottom of the page.

Is it possible to somehow make it smaller in height than 40px? 
Saw a lot of posts about similar thing like this for exaple: [Decreasing height of bootstrap 3.0 navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599778/decreasing-height-of-bootstrap-3-0-navbar)

But none of them worked for my navbar after modifiyng the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
nav{
    min-height:30px !important;
    height:30px;
}
```

And similarly decrease the size for other contents inside

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/0woqrLdL/

Updated one:
http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/0woqrLdL/1/