# Make bootstrap navigation bar tab size smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, navigationbar

I am using twitter bootstrap navigation bar. However, the tab size looks rather big. I would like to adjust the tab to make it smaller. Shorter height and narrower width.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="YYY.html">YYY</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="ZZZ.html">ZZZ</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I got no hints on how to do so from the documentation http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: Have you considered adding a second stylesheet with your own overrides in, or using the bootstrap less/sass and customising it. What have you tried?

Comment: At this moment, I don't know enough until the hints you gave me. Thank you. I did not get any hints from the documentation http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: Cool. Give those a bash and come back if you get stuck

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599778/decreasing-height-of-bootstrap-3-0-navbar