# Adjust the height of NavBar menu in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a basic shiny app in which I want to be able to set the height of the Navbar menu named Navnar! I do not see any choice for setting its height.

```
#ui.r
library(markdown)

navbarPage("Navbar!",
           tabPanel("Plot",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(

                      ),
                      mainPanel(

                      )
                    )
           ),
           tabPanel("Summary"

           ),
           navbarMenu("More",
                      tabPanel("Table"
                      )

           )
)
#server.r
function(input, output, session) {

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To adjust the height of the navbar menu, you have to differentiate between bootstrap versions.  Probably in your shiny application bootstrap version 3.3.4 is used.
Then you can use:

```
tags$style(HTML('.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
                   padding-top:4px !important; 
                   padding-bottom:0 !important;
                   height: 25px;
                 }
                 .navbar {min-height:25px !important;}'))
```

see [Decreasing height of bootstrap 3.0 navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599778/decreasing-height-of-bootstrap-3-0-navbars).

To modify the height you can modify this CSS code adjust the numbers within `height: 25px` and `min-height:25px`.

**Reproducbile example:**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("Navbar!",
         tags$head(
           tags$style(HTML('.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
                            padding-top:4px !important; 
                            padding-bottom:0 !important;
                            height: 25px;
                            }
                           .navbar {min-height:25px !important;}'))
         ),
           tabPanel("Plot",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(

                      ),
                      mainPanel(

                      )
                    )
           ),
           tabPanel("Summary"

           ),
           navbarMenu("More",
                      tabPanel("Table"
                      )

           )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I have been trying to figure out the CSS for this issue forever. Thanks!!